# Change background color of input field using JS

Tags: javascript, html, input, background-color

I'm trying to change background color of an input field when focusing in JS, when its not in focus it should just be a white background color.

I've tried this code, but get an error on it, so I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```js
            function navn(obj, evt) {
                if (evt.type == "focus")
                    style.background = "yellow";  //<--what is style?
                else if (evt.type == "blur") {
                    style.background = "white";
                }
            }
```

```html
 <form>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personlige oplysninger</legend>

                <div>
                    <label for="navn">Udfyld dit fornavn:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="navn" class="navn" id="navn" value="" onclick="navn()" placeholder="Dit fornavn" />*
                    <span id="obsnavn" class="alert"></span>
                </div>

                <input type="button" value="Send" id="send" />

            </fieldset>

        </form>
```

Comment: The 'navn' function is a parameterised function which is taking the particular object and the corresponding event action. So you have to pass those two parameters when calling that function.But since the function call is done only during a click event,  there is no scope for either of the cases to execute. And as for as style is concerned, it is the elements style attribute which is responsible for rendering the css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code :

- your handler function declares an `obj` parameter as the first parameter. When an event is fired, the first element declared in the handler function is a reference to the event object.
- you're trying to react to `blur` or `focus`, but you're using `onclick` on your HTML tag.
- to change your element's background color, you need to modify its `style` object and, in this `style` object, the `backgroundColor` property (the JavaScript equivalent of the `background-color` CSS property).

Here's a solution involving `addEventListener` function. It allows you to attach the same listener to both events : `blur` and `focus`.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("navn");
element.addEventListener("focus", handler);
element.addEventListener("blur", handler);

function handler(evt) {
    if (evt.type == "focus")
        evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; //<--what is style?
    else if (evt.type == "blur") {
        evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Personlige oplysninger</legend>
      <div>
         <label for="navn">Udfyld dit fornavn:</label>
         <input type="text" name="navn" class="navn" id="navn" value="" placeholder="Dit fornavn" />*
         <span id="obsnavn" class="alert"></span>
      </div>
      <input type="button" value="Send" id="send" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: going to take the topic up again, I'm getting this error all of a sudden: 
(( Uncaught ReferenceError: navn is not defined
    at ValideringRequired_12:15 )) - 

not sure what i should do, or what it complains about, other than the name.. Oo'

Comment: NVM, it was a stupid mistake figured it out, again thank you very much for the help ! <3

Comment: NEW QUESTION... XD I want to add an validation on it, but can't seem to get it to work. The validation should show a green background color, instead of pink, when it has reached a minimum of two letters. ^^

I tried with some old notes, but can't get it to work.

Comment: It doesn't seem too complicated. You should really post a new question. You'll get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Because your function as parameter so when you call onclick="navn()" without params it can't work

call it like this :

```
  onblur="blur(this)"  onfocus="focus(this)"

  function blur(obj) {
                obj.style.backgroundColor == "white";
        }
  function focus(obj) {
                obj.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
```

Comment: Okay deleted the parameter, so the error disappeared, but they function doesn't work :s

Comment: Your need to call it like this onclick="navn(**this**)" to pass the element you want to modify. As i see your function is incorrect too.

Comment: focus is reserved so try myfocus(this) and that will work with the focus part.  the blur function won't work as this no longer refers to the input box